# Mounting fails with docker compose but not with docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm mounting a file with docker run:
This works fine:

```
docker run  -v /path/to/myconfig.conf:/path/.to/myconfig.conf ..
```

But in docker-compose it's complaining:

```
volumes:
      - named-volume:/path
      - ./path-in-project/myconfig.conf:/path/.to/myconfig.conf
```

Error:

```
Cannot start service xxx: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/path/to/my/myconfig.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/249085892d6539519b0271c1490f23529c7bcaxxx5a471cc256ed83a6f4d\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/249085892d6539519b0271c1490f23529c7bcaxxx5a471cc256ed83a6f4d/path/.to/myconfig.conf\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\""
: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
```

Comment: This means that `./path-in-project/myconfig.conf` doesn't exist or if it does exists then it is a folder and not a file

Comment: Are you using docker for windows or mac? What is your docker version?

Comment: @yamenk I'm using docker-compose 1.15.0 on ubuntu and Docker version 17.06.1-ce

Comment: @TarunLalwani It does exist. I even copied it from my docker-compose to my host to check (using cat $path). It's relative there for my docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue was the related to ordering of the mount then the approach is not correct. You don't want to be in a situation where

```
volumes:
      - named-volume:/path
      - ./path-in-project/myconfig.conf:/path/.to/myconfig.conf
```

is not same as

```
volumes:
      - ./path-in-project/myconfig.conf:/path/.to/myconfig.conf
      - named-volume:/path
```

Because things may change with changes in `docker-compose` or `docker`. So what you should be doing is that in your Dockerfile symlink the `/path/.to/myconfig.conf` to `/config/myconfig.conf`

And then in your docker volumes use

```
volumes:
      - ./path-in-project/myconfig.conf:/config/myconfig.conf
      - named-volume:/path
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was the sequence. First I have to mount the file into the container, then I have to persist my date:

didn't work:

```
volumes:
      - named-volume:/path
      - ./path-in-project/myconfig.conf:/path/.to/myconfig.conf
```

worked:

```
volumes:
      - ./path-in-project/myconfig.conf:/path/.to/myconfig.conf
      - named-volume:/path
```

Comment: Is any existing data from `/path` being copied to `named-volume` ?

Comment: Yes the rootpath so named-volume/root and than I tried ./path/config.conf:/root/path/to/myconfig.conf